# Javascript coding

Tags: javascript

I am going nuts trying to write a JavaScript code, which requests from the user any sequence of numbers until such user enters 'N'.

If this happens, a message should pop up indicating the user that he reached the end of that sequence and then a new message pops up showing 'all' the numbers the user entered PLUS organising them in crescent order.

Any suggestions, please?

I would appreciate any help as I'm going mad right now thinking of anything.

If the array was specified, then I wouldn't have a problem, but since it's a random array, I can not seem to find the right answer.

Comment: Sounds like school homework …

Comment: Where's the code?  We programmers don't quite like the look of pages without code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is something like this:

1. Get the user's numbers and save them, prefably in an array.
2. Loop through all the numbers and check if the number is N.
3. If so, alert the user.
4. Sort the array, alert the user.

Attempt to code:

```
// All the user's numbers
var UserNumbers = [15, 10, 11, 12, 13];

//The value to search for
var N = 12;


//Loop through the values
for(var i = 0; i < UserNumbers.Length; i++){
     if(UserNumbers[i] == N){
          //The number matches
          alert("You reached the end of the sequence";
     }
}

// I am not sure what you mean with cresent order so that you'll have to solve for yourself.
//Sort the UserNumbers here

//Store the message to show the user

var message = "";

//Loop through the values - now in correct order and save them to the message
for(var i = 0; i < UserNumbers.Length; i++){
     //Add to the message
     message += UserNumbers[i] + " ";
}

//Show the message - all the containing numbers

alert(message);
```

Although this is an helpful community I am pretty certain that we're not made out of teachers here to teach you how to code. Since this sounds to be an homework rather than a real life scenario, talk with your teacher or classmates. Good luck and next time, try to do some research before posting a question - there are plenty of tutorials for beginners out there.